# Exporting the Cross Table visualization to Excel in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to export the Cross Table visualization to an Excel through an Iron Python Script. The below code works perfectly for a data table export. Could you please guide me in exporting it from a Cross Table.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers 
from System.IO import File
writer = 
Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
filtering = 
Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()
stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Q849965\Desktop\SpotfireExport.xls")
names = []
for col in table.Columns:
names.append(col.Name)
writer.Write(stream, table, filtering, names)
stream.Close()
```